# The intervals of real numbers (−∞;0[ , [0;+∞) constitute equivalence classes on ℝ. True or false?

Tags: equivalence-relations

There is no further information given. My thoughts on this question are if there can be equivalence classes if there is no equivalence relation?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Are you sure there is no equivalence relation given? This question does not  make sense then, naturally.

Comment: I'm guessing that the exercise is to identify that these are a partition, and hence there is an equivalence relation that has these as its equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1):

True.  You are given a partition of $R$.  There is a fundamental relationship between partitions and equivalence relations.  The equivalence relation here is that $a$ is related to $b$ if and only if they are in the same set.